# Accessing database Model from HTML Template in DJango

Tags: python, django

In the below code Instead of `{{ i.user }}` I want to access a value from another table with `{{ i.user }}` as matching value. How to done it within HTML

```
{% for i in obj reversed %}
<div class="container">
<blockquote>
    <header> {{ i.topic }} {{ i.user }} </header>
    <p> {{ i.desc }} </p>
    <footer> {{ i.time }} </footer>
</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here are My Models

```
from django.db import models

class Accounts(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    mail=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    likes=models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    time=models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

And I want to get value from `Accounts` using `Blogspot.user` i.e `{{ i.user }}` in template

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you add your models ?

Comment: Added in Question

Comment: Inorder to have something like that you will need relations between models. use ForeignKey. How is your user field related to Accounts ?

Comment: user field in Blogspot matches to phone field in Accounts Models

Comment: There are couple of things. If you want to store details like password, email etc in django, better user Django's User model. Or you can override AbstractBaseUser. That way you can save lot of time/don't have to repeat code. Once a user model is set up, you can give foreignkey to User model from the BlogPost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class Accounts(AbstractBaseUser):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    mail = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Accounts, related_name='accounts')
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    likes = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Now, using foreign key you can access accounts model attributes in your template.